# GWT: How do I mouseUp events?

Tags: java, gwt

In GWT, how do I get the "mouseUp" events when dragging an element?

I'd like to get the following flow:

- mouseDown
- mouseMove
- ... some more mouseMove possibly...
- mouseUp

I can get "mouseDown" and "mouseUp" when I do not move the cursor but the instant I move the cursor, I don't get "mouseUp" events anymore.

I've tried to put `event.preventDefault();` in both "mouseDown" and "mouseMove" handlers to no avail.

Please help.

Comment: the event.preventDefault(); prevents the standard event handling of the browser. So keep it there if you do not want the images and the links to start the drag action of the Browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For DnD you generally need to [`setCapture`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html#setCapture%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29). And don't forget to [`releaseCapture`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html#releaseCapture%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29) when you stop dragging (e.g. mouse up and/or escape key).

Have a look at the code of `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox`, which does just that.

Answer (score 1):

of course the MouseUp handler only works as long as you are on the widtet. That's why you CAN'T use it for drag and drop, because as soon as you move out of the widget the it doesn't react to the MouseUp event.

Here is a simple example:

```
package XXX.client.XXXXXX;

import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseDownEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseDownHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseUpEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseUpHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class MouseUp {
    public MouseUp(){
        Label label = new Label("hallo");
        label.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("backgroundColor","red");
        RootPanel.get().add(label);

        label.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
                Label label = new Label("onMouseDown");
                RootPanel.get().add(label);             
            }
        });
        label.addMouseUpHandler(new MouseUpHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onMouseUp(MouseUpEvent event) {
                Label label = new Label("onMouseUp");
                RootPanel.get().add(label);                     
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you want to use drag and drop functionallity I recomend looking at

- http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/
- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/dnd.html
- GWT Handler ".addDrag...."

Comment: You are right mate. I don't know why you got the negative vote, but the mouse up event is registered for the specific widget. If the mouse up occurs over another item the event is not fired for it is not registered. +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching a MouseUp handler inside the MouseDown event (i.e. in onMouseDown()).